# AugmentedFace mesh with Opencv4Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, augmented-reality, arcore

How to apply OpenCV filters with ARcore's AugmentedFace library? I am trying to create filter for making face look fat.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you've tried, and where you're stuck?

Comment: -> I am not able to acquire camera frame by using this, Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();  in scene.addOnUpdateListener() : it is throwing "DeadlineExceededException".
-> I intend to use this image for some Opencv processing. I am able to add texture and models using AugmentedFace apis but I want to change structure of Face. For that I am not able to figure out .